# Chart.js canvas error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, chart.js

HTML Code:

```
<canvas id="chart" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```

JavaScript (es6):

[image: JavaScript code]

Comment: I think it should read const CHART = $("#chart"). You forgot the # to do an id selector

Comment: I guess I should also point out that $("selector") is jQuery syntax, and to make sure that you have jQuery loaded. I don't see it in your code or tagged in the question

Comment: If you don't want to depend on jQuery, you can rewrite your 3rd line as `const CHART = document.getElementById('chart');` Chart.js can also [take in DOM elements](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart).